# Error reading image file from disk

Tags: c++, c, image, fread

I'm trying to read a jpg file from disk, and copy to a char buffer. The problem is that on the bytes there are some NULL character, and I'm having problems when I read the char buffer.
This is the current code:

```
char* readImg(char* filename)
{
    FILE * pFile;
    char jpgBuffer[20048];
    long lSize;
    errno_t result = fopen_s (&pFile,filename,"rb");
    if (result != 0) {
        printf("Error \n");
    }

    fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell (pFile);
    rewind (pFile);

    result = fread (jpgBuffer,1,lSize,pFile);
    fclose (pFile);

    jpgBuffer[lSize] = '\0';
    return jpgBuffer;
}
```

and the call to the function is:

char* img = readImg("img.jpg");

then, I need to encode into base64, but if I want to know the size of the image buffer with strlen(), I'm getting a size of 4, because the 5 character is a "0".

How can I avoid the NULL characters into image buffer?

Comment: `strlen()` is for null terminated string not arbitrary buffers. You already have the file size. This is exactly the number of bytes read if you read the whole file.

Comment: You cannot avoid NULL bytes as those are valid in JPEGs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may change your function prototype.

```
long readImage(const char* filename, char* buf, long bufSize)
{
    FILE * pFile;
    long lSize;
    errno_t result = fopen_s (&pFile,filename,"rb");
    if (result != 0) {
        printf("Error \n");
    }

    fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell (pFile);
    rewind (pFile);

    if(bufSize < lSize)
    {
        printf("buf too small, needs %lu\n", lSize);
        fclose(pFile);
        return -1;
    }

    result = fread (buf,1,lSize,pFile);
    fclose (pFile);

    return lSize;
}
```

Then you get img data & actual size of it.
If you don't mind using malloc, you can alloc memory for buffer in your function.

```
long readImage(const char* filename, char** pbuf)
{
    FILE * pFile;
    long lSize;
    errno_t result = fopen_s (&pFile,filename,"rb");
    if (result != 0) {
        printf("Error \n");
    }

    fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell (pFile);
    rewind (pFile);

    *pbuf = (char*)malloc(lSize * sizeof(char));
    result = fread (*buf,1,lSize,pFile);
    fclose (pFile);

    return lSize;
}
```

call this function like following, and you need to remember free buffer.

```
char* buf = NULL;
long len = 0;

len = readImage(filename, &buf);

...

free(buf);
```

Comment: For the first version, you probably want the user to also pass the size of the buffer, otherwise there is a strong risk of buffer overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `lSize` you determine in `readImg(...)` as the file size. `strlen` is for null terminated strings. dont use `strlen` to determine image size in bytes.

Note also, that you should assign `jpgBuffer` as a heap variable via `new[]` using `lSize` as the byte size. That way you can return a pointer to heap memory. Your current stack variable `jpgBuffer` will be invalid after the function returns, and hence the pointer to it. This way you also dont have to worry about the situation where you need more bytes than your hardcoded value (which you currently dont check!).

You will also want to return the `lSize` via an input parameter pointer/ref variable so you have a bounds to iterate over later on.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `strlen` to something that is not a string. You should return the size from the `readIamge` function. e.g.

```
char* readImg(char* filename, int *size);
```

If you program in C++ your should instead return an instance of a kind of an image class. This would avoid the splattered location of results.

Further you should never return the address of a local variable as your jpgBuffer. This variable will be overwritten aftern return from function.

Comment: Using C++ does not require classes. C-style coding with C++ is very common as you can user streams, references and templates.

Comment: @CodeClown Just because it is common does not mean it is desirable ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can return your data as a `char*` without any size information.

You can't return your `jpgBuffer`, locally allocated.

Change your function into:

```
int readImg(char* filename, unsigned char* buffer)
{ 
  //...
  result = fread (buffer,1,lSize,pFile);

  return lSize;
}
```

If you can, allocate your buffer in the calling function, it will simplify your code.
However, it you want to avoid buffer overflow, you should pass the size of the allocated buffer to your read function, and return an error/throw an exception if the file size is greater than the size you allocated.

```
int readImg(char* filename, unsigned char* buffer, size_t aSize)
{ 
  //...
  fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
  lSize = ftell (pFile);
  if (lSize > aSize)
  {
    // Manage error case
  }
  //...
  result = fread (buffer,1,lSize,pFile);

  return lSize;
}
```

Keep in mind that this way of coding is more C-style than C++-style. If you wish and can use C++, take advantage of C++ constructs, standard library to improve your code.

Answer (score 0):

`jpgBuffer` is a "binary" buffer, not a "string". Put a null char at the end is non-sense. You should use the `result` variable to read your buffer.